# Change Woocommerce product quantity on a link click with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity

On a product details page, I want to have a few buttons to allow the user to select a specific quantity. e.g. 150, 300, 500. When clicked, the quantity input field should update with the value the user clicked on.

I have tried a simple click function, but it's not firing at all - nothing in console either.

```
<a id="quantity150">150</a>

$('#quantity150').click(function () {
      $('[name="quantity"]').val('150');
      console.log('#quantity150 was clicked');
    });
```

The quantity input field in Woocommerce has the name= "quantity"

An example of this functionality can be seen here: https://www.anypromo.com/trade-show-events/printed-cards/plastic-wallet-card-p730694 (Quantity table - click and it will change the quantity input field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Wordpress you need to replace the `$` alias by `jQuery`. Use instead the following:

```
<a id="quantity150" class="button" href="#">150</a>
<script>
jQuery( function($) {
    $('#quantity150').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('[name="quantity"]').val('150');
        console.log('#quantity150 was clicked');
    });
});
</script>
```

Tested an works on WooCommerce single product pages.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I even had my code remap jQuery to $ and still didn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to add make it add a +1 in the quantity instead of a specific value and make price update accordingly?